# how to set listView with jsonObject from postgresql database more than two fields in android

Tags: android, json, listview

I am try to set list View with jsonObject from postgresql database more than two fields in android.

Comment: FYI, StackOverflow is not a code repository. So its better you refer this link first: [What kind of questions can I ask here?](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions)

Answer (score 0):

You need a [custom ListAdapter](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/List4.html) which maps your databases fields to the actual Views.